# How do I select data with a case statement and group by?

Tags: case

I'm trying to manipulate data a little by using a case statement but can't seem to figure it out.

```
Stops
--------------------
1Stop
1-Stop
1 stop
1 Stop
1stop
1 Stop
2-Stop
```

Im trying to come up with:

```
1-Stop.... 6
2-Stop.... 1
```

What I've tried is:

```
select CASE when 
Stops = '1Stop' OR 
Stops = '1 Stop' OR 
Stops = '1 stop' then '1-Stop' 
ELSE Stops END, count(*) 
from table group by Stops
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you can't use the alias `Stops` in the `GROUP BY`. In your query when you are using the `GROUP BY` it is using the individual values for each row. You'd need to use a subquery to get the result:

```
select stops, count(*) Total
from  
(
  select 
    CASE 
      when Stops in ('1Stop', '1 Stop', '1 stop') then '1-Stop' 
      ELSE Stops
    END as Stops
  from yourtable
) d
group by stops;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26dfd/2).

Or if you don't want to use a subquery, then you could repeat the `CASE` expression in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select 
  CASE 
    when Stops in ('1Stop', '1 Stop', '1 stop') then '1-Stop' 
    ELSE Stops
  END as Stops,
  count(*)  as Total
from yourtable
group by 
  CASE 
    when Stops in ('1Stop', '1 Stop', '1 stop') then '1-Stop' 
    ELSE Stops
  END
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26dfd/4)

Comment: Has anyone compared them by efficiency?

Comment: does this hold across all SQL variants/dialects? does postgres have the same limitation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19848930/11107541

Answer (score -1):

you can also try
select
CASE
when Stops in ('1Stop', '1 Stop', '1 stop') then '1-Stop'
ELSE Stops
END as Stops,
count(*)  as Total
from yourtable
group by
1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).